# getting an array from another file in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have these methods.
 I have defined a char array in `stringcontent.h` file and that array is taken from a method in another file`test.c`.

```
// stringcontent.h
char content1[] = "blahblah";
void  get_char_array(int which,char  *buffer){
   if(which == 1)
      buffer = content1;
      printf("%s",buffer); // prints : "blahblah"
   // and so on.....
}

// test.c
#include "stringcontent.h"
main(){
    char *buf;
    get_char_array(1,buf);
    printf("%s",buf); // prints rubbish rubbish !!!
}
```

I have to stick to this method interface(function signatures) and how can I fix this?

Comment: The code you called "stringcontent.h" in fact must be a "stringcontent.c". In "stringcontent.h" you must only declare `void  get_char_array(int which,char  *buffer);`. If you don't do so, you'll end up having linker errors. @rbelli's response seems to be what you need, so I took the freedom to edit his response.

Comment: @D-Shan: Off topic, but i noticed your avatar, and i wholly approve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand, you want to get the variable using the function get_char_array. Then If I understand you need to do the following (change the get_char_function to receive a pointer to pointer to a char):

```
// stringcontent.h
char content1[] = "blahblah";
void  get_char_array(int which,char  **buffer){
   if(which == 1)
      *buffer = content1;
      printf("%s",*buffer); // prints : "blahblah"
   // and so on.....
}

// test.c
#include "stringcontent.h"
main(){
    char *buf;
    get_char_array(1,&buf);
    printf("%s",buf); // prints "blahblah" !!!
}
```

---

EDIT:

Put your **declarations** in the header file and **implementation** in the ".c" or you will have linker errors.

```
// stringcontent.h
#ifndef __STRINGCONTENT_H
#    define __STRINGCONTENT_H

void  get_char_array(int which,char  **buffer);

#endif

// stringcontent.c
char content1[] = "blahblah";
void  get_char_array(int which,char  **buffer){
   if(which == 1)
      *buffer = content1;
      printf("%s",*buffer); // prints : "blahblah"
   // and so on.....
}

// test.c
#include "stringcontent.h"
main(){
    char *buf;
    get_char_array(1,&buf);
    printf("%s",buf); // prints "blahblah" !!!
}
```

To compile (if using gcc):

```
gcc -Wall test.c stringcontent.c -o test
```

Note you don't need to "export" `content1` since the only thing you need, a pointer, is returned by a function.

---

---

Here is another solution using strcpy. In this case you don't need to pass a pointer to pointer.

```
// stringcontent.h
char content1[] = "blahblah";
void  get_char_array(int which,char  *buffer){
   if(which == 1)
      strcpy(buffer,content1);
      printf("%s",buffer); // prints : "blahblah"
   // and so on.....
}

// test.c
#include "stringcontent.h"
#define GOOD_SIZE (100)
main(){
    char buf[GOOD_SIZE];
    get_char_array(1,buf);
    printf("%s",buf); // prints "blahblah" !!!
}
```

In this case you have to take care to allocate sufficient size in buf before call the get_char_array.

I prefer the first solution, it doesn't need to use the strcpy. And if you don't allocate sufficient space in the buf you can have problems. One solution is to pass the size of the buf in the function and check it before strcpy or use strncpy.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. But here the method is called like (1,**&buf**) rather that (1,**buf**) . Is that way possible ?

Comment: Yes, in this case you need to pass the address of the pointer as you will be modifying the pointer.

Comment: I mean is there a way to call like (1,**buf**) but not like (1,**&buf**).That's what I wanted to say - "I have to stick to this method interface" .

Comment: You can change you method to `return` the pointer instead or assigning it to `buffer`. That would even be cleaner.

Comment: @D-Shan: I edited the answer adding another option, in this case you use the interface you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
extern char content1[];
```

declaration in `stringcontent.h` and put your array definition and function definition in a file named `stringcontent.c`. You should not put object and function definitions in header files.